# Org-mode beamer, stop a 2-column block and display following text throughout page width

Tags: org-mode, beamer

I want to compose a beamer frame which consists in two blocks side-by-side, followed by text laid out throughout the page width, that is under the 2 blocks above. Producing the two blocks works fine. However, none of my attempts (e.g putting a '-' to start a new list, putting more than a couple of empty lines after the last block text) could stop the block section.
Here is a MWE.

```
*** Left block                         :B_column:
    :PROPERTIES:
    :BEAMER_env: block
    :BEAMER_col: 0.5
    :END:

     My left block of text here

*** Right block                        :B_column:
    :PROPERTIES:
    :BEAMER_env: block
    :BEAMER_col: 0.48
    :END:   

    My right block of text here. 


- I'd like this piece of text to go below left and right 
  blocks of text throughout the page width but it stays 
  in the right block.
```

The generated LaTeX source for this will typically be, for right block:

```
\begin{column}{0.48\textwidth}
\begin{block}{Right block}
        My right block of text here. 

\begin{itemize}
\item I'd like this piece of text to go below left and right 
      blocks of text throughout the page width but it stays 
      in the right block.
\end{itemize}

\end{block}
\end{column}
```

while i would like the \end{column} to appear before \begin{itemize}.
I guess we can tell Beamer to stop the block but could not find out.

**Edit**: *i found meanwhile a workaround solution, which is to create a new block without title (using ***[blank]) to contain the fullwidth text (see below). However, this is not exactly what i expected as this last block has all the properties of a block, in particular a background color.*

```
*** Left block                         :B_column:
        :PROPERTIES:
        :BEAMER_env: block
        :BEAMER_col: 0.5
        :END:

         My left block of text here

    *** Right block                        :B_column:
        :PROPERTIES:
        :BEAMER_env: block
        :BEAMER_col: 0.48
        :END:   

        My right block of text here. 


      ***  
      I'd like this piece of text to go below left and right 
      blocks of text throughout the page width but it stays 
      in the right block.
```

**Edit 2**: *The solution proposed by rvf0068 works well. Let me post the whole source code*. Using org-mode shortcuts, Ctrl-C Ctrl-B when positioned on the ***[blank] headline, prompts you for the block type, for which 'i' (B_ignoreheading) is what you need._

```
*** Left block                         :B_column:
        :PROPERTIES:
        :BEAMER_env: block
        :BEAMER_col: 0.5
        :END:

         My left block of text here

    *** Right block                        :B_column:
        :PROPERTIES:
        :BEAMER_env: block
        :BEAMER_col: 0.48
        :END:   

        My right block of text here. 


      ***                               :B_ignoreheading:
      :PROPERTIES:
      :BEAMER_env: ignoreheading
      :END:
      I'd like this piece of text to go below left and right 
      blocks of text throughout the page width but it stays 
      in the right block.
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the property `BEAMER_env` with value `ignoreheading` to the heading that interrupts the columns.

```
***                                                             :B_ignoreheading:
    :PROPERTIES:
    :BEAMER_env: ignoreheading
    :END:

    #+beamer: \vspace{1cm}  
    I'd like this piece of text to go below left and right    
    blocks of text throughout the page width but it stays    
    in the right block.
```

Note that I added `#+beamer: \vspace{1cm}` since otherwise it looks cramped.

Comment: Thanks ! This is indeed the solution. I am going to post a second edit to show the whole source code.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
** Test
*** Top two-column block                                          :B_columns:
    :PROPERTIES:
    :BEAMER_env: columns
    :END:
**** Left block                                                    :B_column:
     :PROPERTIES:
     :BEAMER_env: block
     :BEAMER_col: 0.5
     :END:

- My left block of text here

**** Right block                                                   :B_column:
     :PROPERTIES:
     :BEAMER_env: block
     :BEAMER_col: 0.50
     :END:   

- My right block of text here. 

*** Bottom two-column block                                       :B_columns:
    :PROPERTIES:
    :BEAMER_env: columns
    :END:
**** @@beamer: ~@@                                                  :B_block:
     :PROPERTIES:
     :BEAMER_env: block
     :BEAMER_col: 0.99
     :END:
- I'd like this piece of text to go below left and right blocks of
  text throughout the page width but it stays in the right block.
**** @@beamer: ~@@                                                  :B_block:
     :PROPERTIES:
     :BEAMER_env: block
     :BEAMER_col: 0.01
     :END:
```

The trick is to:

1. Embed your two blocks in a two-column columns block
2. Create another two-columns section below
3. Put your stuff in the left bottom column.

Notes:

- Tried one-column section in step 2, but adjustment looked weird. Same with ignoreheading solution by @rvf0068
- Width sum of two-columns should be equal.
- Bottom left column almost full width.
- Bottom right column very small and empty.
- The @@beamer: ~@@ is to trick org-mode to use a blank title.

I'm sure there are better solutions (single-column in step 2) to sort out the adjustment, but this worked for me.